# how to input to table $_POST[name$i] variable name as variable

Tags: php, html, mysql, http-post

My $_POST name is :
$_POST[p_new_1], $_POST[p_new_2], $_POST[p_new_3], etc. depends on the value of $_POST[number] 
(above is $_POST[number] equal to 4).
Now I need to add that value to table by :

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `tablename` (`Name`) VALUES ('$_POST[p_new_1]')");
```

But it only work if I know that $_POST[number]=2; sometimes $_POST[number] has no value or value greater than 2, in general case it should be:

```
if($_POST[number]!=NULL)
for ($i = 1; $i < $_POST[number]; $i++) {
    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `table` (`Name`) VALUES ('$_POST['p_new_'.$i]')");
}
```

But using this code I always got error. I also tried:

```
if($_POST[number]!=NULL)
for ($i = 1; $i < $_POST[number]; $i++) {
    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `table` (`Name`) VALUES ('$_POST['p_new_$i']')");
}
```

But same error.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in /test.php on line 18
```

How is the correct way to write it ?

Comment: Can you write the error, too?

Comment: Yes, I added to my original post.

Comment: you can use `isset($_POST['number'])`. be aware of your quotations and `{}` on your condition statements

Comment: Parametrise / Prepare your queries or forgo protection from sql injection: INSERT INTO `table` (`Name`) VALUES (?).

Comment: replace this '$_POST['p_new_$i']' to '".$_POST['p_new_'.$i]."'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
if(isset($_POST[number]) and  is_numeric($_POST[number])){
   for ($i = 1; $i < $_POST[number]; $i++) {
      $name=isset($_POST['p_new_'.$i]) ? $_POST['p_new_'.$i] : "";
      mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO table (Name) VALUES ('".$name."')");
  }
}
```

Comment: I have to accept this answer although I still need the single quote at `Name` on above code. Yes, it works now ! Thank you and thanks to all member's suggestions, you all rock !!

Answer (score 2):

Your double quotes are confusing the process. Change it to:

```
if($_POST[number]!=NULL)
for ($i = 1; $i < $_POST[number]; $i++) {
    $key = 'p_new_'.$i;
    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `table` (`Name`) VALUES ('".$_POST[$key]."')");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
if(($_POST['number']!=NULL) and  (is_numeric($_POST['number'])))
for ($i = 1; $i < $_POST['number']; $i++) 
{
    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `table` (`Name`) VALUES (".$_POST['p_new_'.$i].")");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, with my very limited knowledge, I can spot one issue:

The variable needs to be in double quotes in order for the value of it to be passed to the query correctly:

```
".$_POST['p_new_'.$i]."
```

This prevents the variable from being considered as a string.